# No route matches when using Rack application with Rails and Rspc

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, routes, rack

I've been having issues with controller spec since moving some code to a Rack application within my Rails code. The routes work perfectly when running as a server, just not via Rspec.

This is my route definition:

```
match ':username', to: Rack::CatchAllRouter.new, constraints: { format: 'html' }, via: [:get, :put, :patch]
```

The following code is my controller spec:

```
describe UsersController do
  describe "#show" do
    subject { get :show, username: 'test-user' }
    it { is_expected.to be_successful }
    it { is_expected.to render_template('users/show') }
  end
end
```

The error I receive is as follows:

```
No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"users", :username=>"test-user"}
```

I don't understand why this should have to go through the router at all as this should be testing just the controller rather than going through the whole request setup.

I'm also able to get this working via a request spec and constructing the URL, just not a controller spec.

Comment: Have you found a solution? I'm having the same issue.

Answer (score -3):

probably your params in the route doesn't match the params you send in spec

Comment: The params match, it routes fine when I use 'users#show' instead of the rack application